# Facebook Mobile App. Like to continue

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to make a mobile app that makes a user like a certain page to continue.

I know that to check if a user has liked a page for a regular app you can make the app a tab of that page, and then use the `signed_request` to see if the user has like the page.

How would this work in mobile? I have looked to see if you can include a mobile page as a tab, but I couldn't find much information.

Can you include a mobile app as a tab? If not then how would you make a user like a page before entering?

I will be using jquery mobile and javascript for most of the non back end work.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Even if I knew how to do this, I wouldn't reveal how to force users into liking things just to get access to your webpages.

Comment: What does "make the app a tab of that page" mean, in terms of code? Can you post an example?

Comment: @BryanH - Go to this site: http://www.facebook.com/#!/oreo?sk=wall all the items after wall and info are tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

You can subscribe to events . Following event will be raised when some user clicks "Like" button.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
      //redirect or perform some action
    });
```

Source : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: I tried that out. It works, but only if the user has yet to previously like the page. I guess the only way I can do this is by asking for user likes in the permissions. Ill accept the answer though since it does answer the question